# What is the grep command to extract anything between two keywords

Tags: shell, grep

I want to extract all the numbers between `<id>` and `</id>`, like this:

```
<id>123</id> 
<id>456</id>
```

to get a file which contains

```
123
456
```

I'm pretty new to grep, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can make it:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=<id>)\d+' file
123
456
```

it looks for any numbers after `<id>` and prints them.

- `-o` stands for *"Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line"*.
- `-P` stands for *"Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression"*.
- `(?<=<id>)\d+` means: match only `\d+` following `<id>`. More info in [Regex tutorial - Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and in [this nice explanation by sudo_O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13887746/1983854).

Comment: Thanks very much. Could you explain a bit about (?<=<id>)\d+